org.apache.hc.client5.http.ClientProtocolException: Target host is not specified
I am trying just to hit a GET API using Java but I am getting this error every time (Error is the title of this question)
This error is happening at restclient.get() line.
Help here.
I have provided all the class:
Restclient class ->
public class Restclient {
    // Hit get method
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void get(String url) throws IOException, ParseException, URISyntaxException {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);

            System.out.println("Response status: " + response.getReasonPhrase());

            int statuscode = response.getCode();
            System.out.println("Status code : " + statuscode);

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            JsonObject responseJson = JsonParser.parseString(responseString).getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println("Response from API : " + responseJson);

            Header[] headerarray = response.getHeaders();
            Map<String, String> allheader = new HashMap<>();
            for (Header header : headerarray) {
                allheader.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println(allheader);
        }
    }
}

Baseclass ->
public class BaseClass {

    public Properties prop;

    public BaseClass() {
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("app/src/main/java/com/mypackage/config/config.properties");
            prop.load(ip);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Testclass ->
public class GetAPITest extends BaseClass {

    BaseClass base;
    String endpoint;
    String apiurl;
    String url;
    Restclient restClient;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        base = new BaseClass();
        apiurl = prop.getProperty("url");
        endpoint = prop.getProperty("endpoint");
        url = apiurl + endpoint;
    }

    @Test
    public void getAPITest() throws ParseException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
        restClient = new Restclient();
        restClient.get(url);
    }
}

config.properties file ->
url = https://reqres.in/
endpoint = api/users?page=1
